# the meaning of 'butt' here

Tags: word-meaning

From *The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz* by Mordecai Richler:

> Duddy lit a cigarette off ***his butt***. "How's Auntie Ida?" he asked.

Is the '**butt**' buttocks or the part of a cigarette that is left after it has been smoked?

Comment: The first interpretation would imply quite the interesting context...

Comment: I've heard of people striking matches off their butt[ocks] (eg, when wearing denim), so this confused me for a second.

Comment: @barrycarter: that's exactly what I was confused about. I remember seeing something like that in movies.

Comment: I think John Wayne did it, but it was more off his hip than his butt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the butt of the last cigarette that he'd been smoking. It's an action characteristic of chain smoking.

Comment: One query - why is "his" correct here, instead of necessarily being "its"?

Comment: @GoodDeeds - because it's his (previous) cigarette.

Comment: But wouldn't it then be "Duddy lit _his_ cigarette off _its_ butt"? Wouldn't "a" suggest that it hasn't been referenced before?

Comment: Using *its* in that context would end up referring to the cigarette in that sentence - which is not the previous cigarette, its the next (new) one.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I see it as having an ellipsed term: "Duddy lit a cigarette off his [old cigarette's] butt."

Comment: It's the defining feature of chain-smoking.